# Serving files with authorization in an Owin self hosted application

Tags: c#, owin

I have a self hosted application using Owin and no ASP.MVC of any type, so there is no web.config in the application.

I have enabled cookie authentication and my own authorization provider mechanism which works perfectly fine.
My application serves some static contents using the the next code:

```
appBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Images"),
    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"./Images"),
});
```

But that content is not protected by the Owin authentication, what would be the easiest way to protect the files?

*ideally not having to implement the whole file serving myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I've managed to do it in this way:

```
        var contentFileServer = new FileServerOptions()
        {
            RequestPath = new PathString("/Content"),
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"./Content"),
        };

        contentFileServer.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = (context) => 
        {
            if (context.OwinContext.Authentication.User == null)
            {
                // Reply an unauthorized
                context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        };

        appBuilder.UseFileServer(contentFileServer);
```

Looks like a reasonable way of doing it.

Comment: Note: This only sets the HTTP status code, under the hood it also sends the file requested, you can see it in the Network tab in browsers console...

Comment: The File will still be part of the request body:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.staticfiles.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse

Comment: This doesn't work. I've added the NuGet packages and your code, builds. But static files under the **attachments** folder are still happily served even if OwinContext.User is null. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

@Cristian T answer needs to be extended. See my comment: "This only sets the HTTP status code, under the hood it also sends the file requested, you can see it in the Network tab in browsers console..."

So, to disable sending the file you have to write the response yourself, before the `StaticFileContext` will. The `OnPrepareResponse` function should be:

```
contentFileServer.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = (context) => 
{
    if (context.OwinContext.Authentication.User == null)
    {
        // Reply an unauthorized
        const string unauthorizedBody = "Unauthorized"; // or HTML or anything else
        ctx.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        ctx.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Set("Content-Length", unauthorizedBody.Length.ToString());
        ctx.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/html");
        ctx.OwinContext.Response.Write(unauthorizedBody);
    }
};
```

This way, the server returns "Unauthorized" instead of the file requested.

Comment: The File will still be part of the request body:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.staticfiles.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse

Comment: @Valter Nope, I checked with a proxy and in this case it isn't

Comment: well when i look at the developer tools on firefox/chrome i see the file (bits) append to the body after the Unauthorized.

Comment: @Valter You must be doing something wrong then or not using the same version of a library maybe. I just rechecked this and neither FF dev tools neither my debugging proxy shows the file. It just shows "Unauthorized" as expected. Proof: https://imgur.com/a/JjITh What does it write in the response's Content-Length header?